# Workflows - Multiconditional

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow

I need to create a work flow that is multi conditional and am not sure how to or if it the best approach.
I have a form that has a series of toggle fields that relate to departments. If a department is selected I need only the general form information and specific department information to be sent out in an email notification to them - not the other department information -  we do not want them see the other department data.
Is a multi conditional workflow the answer of multiple workflows?

Answer (score 1):

I think you were on the right track thinking about throwing in IF conditions into the logic of your workflow.

You can have separate e-mail actions based on departments (not sure how many you have). Alternatively, you could maybe store that information in a separate list and then do a lookup for the text (if it's just stored in a text column). Or if you maintain the information in a page, just include the URL to that page in the e-mail step.

Regardless, it's conditions vs multi-workflows and you'll be golden!

Comment: Thanks Jared. I will try it out and see how I go. There are only 8 departments that need to have a subset of the form information. I think it will work ok.